# View of UIViewController doesn't appear in UIPopoverController

Tags: objective-c, ios5, view, uipopovercontroller

i made an .xib file and added my buttons and labels. Then I created UIViewController files and added it to file's Owner class as custom class then connect its view with ViewController.

Then I went to my UIView that has button to display the UIPopoverController when I press it and created the button Action then I wrote in this Action

```
OpenFileViewController *openfileview = [[OpenFileViewController alloc] init];
    //int subcount = openfileview.view.subviews.count;
    UIPopoverController *openfilediaglog = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:openfileview];
    openpopoverController = openfilediaglog;
    [openpopoverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 460)]; 
    [openpopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0,400, 500) inView:self permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

when I press the button the UIPopoverController appear but empty i couldn't find the problem !!!? where is it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your OpenFileViewController has a xib instead of programatic interface you can't use `init`

```
// OpenFileViewController *openfileview = [[OpenFileViewController alloc] init];

OpenFileViewController *openfileview = [[OpenFileViewController alloc] initWithNibName:NIBNAME bundle:NSBUNDLE];
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this instead OpenFileViewController init.

```
OpenFileViewController *openfileview = [[OpenFileViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"OpenFileViewController" bundle:nil];
```